# Web collection from Google data page

Tags: perl, web, web-scraping

I am trying to collect the data from this page:

https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c07bc5cf-5c09-4156-a903-3e7acd02721a/page/ql6IC

I usually use PERL/LWP to GET the page then parse, but this page does not return the visible elements, just the initial Google goo.

Looking to grab the Number of Confirmed Cases and the date updated at the bottom of the page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this page uses javascript to modify the DOM so you cannot access the data without first running the javascript code. You could try [Selenium::Chrome](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Chrome) instead of `LWP::UserAgent`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to access the data after javascript has modified the DOM using [`Selenium::Chrome`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Chrome) :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Chrome;
# Enter your driver path here. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/
#  for download instructions
my $driver_path = '/home/hakon/chromedriver/chromedriver';
my $driver = Selenium::Chrome->new( binary => $driver_path );
$driver->get("https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c07bc5cf-5c09-4156-a903-3e7acd02721a/page/ql6IC");
sleep 5;  # modify this sleep period such that the page is fully loaded before continuing 
my $elem = $driver->find_element_by_class_name('tableBody');
# Do something with the table..
```

**Update**

To avoid specifying the sleep limit above you can use the `wait_until()` function from  [`Selenium::Waiter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Waiter), for example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Chrome;
use Selenium::Waiter;
# Enter your driver path here. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/
#   for download instructions
my $driver_path = '/home/hakon/chromedriver/chromedriver';
my $driver = Selenium::Chrome->new(
    binary => $driver_path,
    # avoid printing error from find_element_by_class_name() when class is not found,
    #   see the below wait_until() call. The error message will be on the form:
    #
    # "Error while executing command: no such element: no such element:
    #    Unable to locate element"
    #
    error_handler => sub { my $msg = $_[1]; die $msg if $msg !~ /\Qno such element\E/}
);
$driver->get("https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c07bc5cf-5c09-4156-a903-3e7acd02721a/page/ql6IC");
my $timeouts = $driver->get_timeouts();
say "Current implicit timeout = ", $timeouts->{implicit};
$driver->set_implicit_wait_timeout(0);
say "Updated implicit wait timeout to 0 ms";
my $timeout = 30;
my $start_time = time;
my $elem = wait_until {
       $driver->find_element_by_class_name('tableBody')
   } timeout => $timeout, interval => 1;
if ( $elem ) {
    my $elapsed = time - $start_time;
    say "Found element after $elapsed seconds";
}
else {
    say "Could not find tableBody element after $timeout seconds";
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will get the chromedriver and Selenium module installed to test.

Comment: This worked wonderfully!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!

Cheers!